# why sklearn.svm.SVC's attribute coef_ has shape = [n_class * (n_class-1) / 2, n_features]?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm using sklearn.svm.SVC with linear kernel and i want to get the feature importance, so i use the attribute coeff_ which (as explained here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) is an array with the shape [n_class * (n_class-1) / 2, n_features], for example, im my case, i have 10 classes and 54 features, so the shape is [45,54],

Why i get 45 arrays of weights? what is the meaning of each one of these arrays? Beacuse intuitively i would have expected 10 arrays of weights, one for each class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape is **indeed** `[n_class * (n_class-1) / 2, n_features]` but why?

This is because if you have **more than 2 classes** i.e. if you have a problem that is **not** **binary** then the **multiclass support of the function is handled according to an one-vs-one scheme.**

---

Example:
If you have 3 classes let's say `1,2,3` then the classifier will be fitted for the cases: `1vs2`, `1vs3` and `2vs3`. So here, we have `n_class * (n_class-1) / 2 = 3 * (3-1) / 2 = 3`.

---

Let's verify the above:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3]) # 3 classes

clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, y)

print(clf.coef_)
[[-0.5        -0.5       ]
 [-0.46153846 -0.30769231]
 [-1.          0.        ]]
```

**Here, in the `clf.coef_`, each row corresponds to the above cases `1vs2`, `1vs3` and `2vs3`, respectively. So, first row i.e. `[-0.5, -0.5]` gives you the coefficient of the first and second feature/variable for the case of `1vs2` classification fitting.**

---

P.S: In case of binary classification, then `print(clf.coef_)` will return only one line for the `1vs2` classification case.

---

Concerning the order of the rows:

> In the case of “one-vs-one” SVC, the layout of the attributes is a
>   little more involved. In the case of having a linear kernel, the
>   attributes coef_ and intercept_ have the shape [n_class * (n_class -
>   1) / 2, n_features] and [n_class * (n_class - 1) / 2] respectively.
>   This is similar to the layout for LinearSVC described above, with each
>   row now corresponding to a binary classifier. The order for classes 0
>   to n is “0 vs 1”, “0 vs 2” , … “0 vs n”, “1 vs 2”, “1 vs 3”, “1 vs n”,
>   . . . “n-1 vs n”.

Paragraph found in https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html